# How to get the right Element out of a REST call

Tags: angular, rest, api, angular5, angular6

I try to call my REST API, which returns an JSON Object including a session_token.
I only need that session_token, but how do I get it?

```
this.http.post(this.tokenURL, this.tokenCall).subscribe(res => {
  this.token = res.session_token;
});
```

This is my try, but Angular won't compile because he doesnt know if session_token exists at compile time. How do I just get the session_token out of it? If I declare it in the token itself, it won't work either.

Thanks for your help

Comment: where do you call this post request, in constructor or ngOnInıt ?

Comment: an own Function called "apiCall()" which gets called in ngOnInit, yes

Comment: so what's the exact question?Sorry dont understand this : "but Angular won't compile because he doesnt know if session_token exists at compile time"

Comment: You need to call `res.json()` to get the object first.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this (with HttpClient from HttpClientModule)

```
this.http.post<{session_token}>(this.tokenURL, this.tokenCall)
 .subscribe(res => { 
  this.token = res.session_token; 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, for anyone who is curious.
I declare an Object of the type "any" and assign it the response data.

```
let response:any = {};
this.http.post(this.tokenURL, this.tokenCall).subscribe(res => {
  if(res.hasOwnProperty("session_token")){
    response = res;
    this.token = response.session_token;
  }
```

That might not be a good style but the only workaround I found.